# EditText null after calling findViewById()

Tags: java, android, xml

I've had this issue for the past couple days, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I feel like I've written these exact lines of code a million times. I have two EditText components that I'm trying to get the text from when a button is clicked. But for some reason I'm getting a NullPointer exception for both the EditTexts. Calling findViewById() finds the buttons just fine, but doesn't seem to resolve the EditTexts.

When I run the application, the UI appears and I am able to click the "Connect" button. Logcat tells me the NullPointerException is coming from line 46 in "MainActivity.java", which is where the first EditText is. I've run tests and have verified that they are null. I can't seem to figure out why though, any insight on resolving the matter would be greatly appreciated. I'm running Android Studio v1.0.2.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private TextView _ipLabel;

private EditText _ipInput;
private EditText _portInput;

private Button _hostButton;
private Button _connectButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _ipLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ip_label);

    _ipInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_input);
    _portInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port_input);

    _hostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hostButton);
    _connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);

    _hostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Host Button", "Clicked");
        }
    });
    _connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String connectionAddr = _ipInput.getText().toString() + ":";
        connectionAddr+= _portInput.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Host", connectionAddr);
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ip_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-.-.-.-"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hostButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Host   "/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IP: "/>
    <EditText
        android:label="@+id/ip_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PORT: "/>
    <EditText
        android:label="@+id/port_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connect"/></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your seems ok.. where is your logcat?

Comment: You are using `android:label="@+id/port_input` instead of `android:id="@+id/port_input"` etc

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? I'm trying to see where the problem is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<EditText
    android:label="@+id/port_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here it isn't `android:label`, it should be `android:id`.

Change this to,

```
android:id="@+id/port_input"
```

Also to the other edit text used.

Comment: -_- I'm an idiot. Thank you, just needed a fresh pair of eyes on this. My brain must be fried from taking finals.

Comment: Happens at times. Glad I could help!

Comment: We've all been there!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<EditText
    android:label="@+id/ip_input" // <-- this should be an id not a label
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

use:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Totally over looked that, thank you. No idea why I used label.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ip_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-.-.-.-"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hostButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Host   "/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IP: "/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ip_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PORT: "/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/port_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connect"/></LinearLayout>
```